# Cycle once and stop on the first slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bxslider

I am trying to make the `bxslider` cycle through three slides and then return to the first slide and stop the slideshow in that position. I've tried different bits of code but I can't find anything that specifically addresses this kind of action. Any help is appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    autoControls: true,
    pause: 5000,
    slideMargin: 0
    });
});
```

Comment: Please show the code you've tried and describe what issues you had with it.

Comment: How many slides you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of would be to insert a second copy of the first slide at the end so you have three slides and then another copy of the first and you tell it not to auto-repeat.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        auto: true,
        autoControls: true,
        pause: 5000,
        infiniteLoop: false,   // don't auto-repeat
        slideMargin: 0
    });
});
```

Beyond that, you could specify a callback and after the third slide finishes displaying, you could stop the auto-advance and then tell it to goto the first slide.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        auto: true,
        autoControls: true,
        pause: 5000,
        infiniteLoop: false,
        slideMargin: 0,
        onSlideNext: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
            if (newIndex >= 3) {
                slider.stopAuto();
                slider.goToSlide(0);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

---

If you only have three slides (a fact you haven't included that would have helped us), then perhaps you won't get an `onSlideNext` event when `infiniteLoop` is off.  In that case, you could use the `onSlideAfter` method and trigger after showing the third slide.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        auto: true,
        autoControls: true,
        pause: 5000,
        infiniteLoop: false,
        slideMargin: 0,
        onSlideAfter: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
            if (newIndex >= 2) {
                slider.stopAuto();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    slider.goToSlide(0);
                }, 5000);    // put whatever time here you want the 3rd slide to show
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  I've offered two options that would do exactly what the OP asked for.

Comment: I attempted to use your second bit of code, but it stops on the third slide and doen's return to the first. Im trying to see if I can make it work. Thanks.

Comment: @Xochi - are you getting any script errors in the console?  Per the [documentation for bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/options), the `goToSlide()` method should allow you to set it to any slide you want.

Comment: Yes it was three slides, sorry!

Comment: Thanks for your help, its working now. much appreciated jfriend

Comment: @Xochi - since it looks like you may be relatively new to StackOverflow, do you realize that when someone provides an answer that solved your problem, you should select that answer as the "best answer" by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer?  That indicates to the community that your problem is solved and that this answer helped you.  It also rewards you with some reputation points for following the correct procedure here and rewards the person who provided the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this using callback?

```
 var slider =  $('.bxslider').bxSlider(options); //your default options here.
 $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  onSlideAfter: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
    //if slide number is 3
    if(newIndex === 2){
       slider.goToSlide(0);
       slider.stopAuto();
    }
  });
```

What this code will do is, it will callback onSlideAfter function as soon as the slide is changed.. If the slide index is 3 then the code will stop autoplay after going to first slide..

Used callbacks and methods :

1. onSlideAfter (callback)
2. goToSlide (method)

Reference here : http://bxslider.com/options

Comment: Thanks but this code is not working, I'm trying to get it to work right now.